# Parenthesis don't show in built-in iPhone calculator app

Tags: ios

When you open the iOS's built in calculator app and rotate iPhone you get the scientific calculator.

I am trying to use parenthesis `(` `)` to write something like `(2+2)/4` but the parenthesis don't appear!

How do I enter that expression?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The built-in calculator doesn't offer any visual clues to let you know you've opened a sub-group operation in an expression. The only thing that tips you off is you'll get a sub-result after you close the group show up in the display. For example, enter the following:

```
5 + ( 3 + 3 )
```

After you type the opening `(` you don't see anything on the display. But when you press the closing `)` the display shows you `6` to tip you off to the fact that the `3 + 3` operation was performed.

I prefer the [TouchCalc](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/touchcalc/id286091993?mt=8) app myself. It will show a small `(` in the lower left corner of the display when you open a sub-expression grouping so you know you're actually perserving your order of operations as intended.

Comment: Apple can really negativtely suriprise me

Answer (score 0):

It does not function correctly depending on the equation.  I type in:

600/(¹3)=

and I get 200

The correct answer is 346.41016......

The calculator does not follow the order of operations for parenthesis in a consistent manner.